# How can I click on a View in ListView specific row position

Tags: android-listview, position, row, android-espresso, ui-testing

I have a ListView:

[image]

And I want to click on a specific button within a ListView.

If I want to select with the onData selector:

```
onData(withId(R.id.button))
                .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.list_view))
                .atPosition(1)
                .perform(click());
```

And I get this error:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'load adapter data' on view 'with id: com.example.application:id/list_view'.
...
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`onData()` requires an object matcher for the item that you are interested in. If you don't care about the data in the adapter you can use `Matchers.anything()` to effectively match all objects in the adapter. Alternatively you can create a data matcher (depending on data that is stored in the adapter) for your item and pass it in for a more deterministic test.

As for the button - what you are looking for is an `onChildsView()` method, which allows to pass a viewmatcher for the descendant of the listitem, that was matched in the `onData().atPosition()`

And as a result your test will look something like this:

```
    onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.list_view))
            .atPosition(1)
            .onChildView(withId(R.id.button))
            .perform(click());
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't see this onChildsView before. BTW the nthChildDescendant function may be useful for other stuff :)

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround which don't use the ListView data, and the `.getPosition(index)`, instead checks that the the view with the specific id is the descendant of the ListView specific position View.

```
public static Matcher<View> nthChildsDescendant(final Matcher<View> parentMatcher, final int childPosition) {
    return new TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(Description description) {
            description.appendText("with " + childPosition + " child view of type parentMatcher");
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {

            while(view.getParent() != null) {
                if(parentMatcher.matches(view.getParent())) {
                    return view.equals(((ViewGroup) view.getParent()).getChildAt(childPosition));
                }
                view = (View) view.getParent();
            }

            return false;
        }
    };
}
```

Example of usage:

```
onView(allOf(
       withId(R.id.button), 
       nthChildsDescendant(withId(R.id.list_view), 1)))
   .perform(click());
```